# Can Peano arithmetic define the set of base 10 palindromic numbers?

Tags: model-theory, peano-axioms, palindrome

A base 10 palindrome is a number that when written in base 10 and the digits are reversed, gives the same number. I am wondering, can Peano arithmetic define the set of base 10 palindromes? I don't even need to be given an explicit definition, merely a proof that that set is definable in the language of Peano Arithmetic. An explicit definition of that set, using abbreviations if necessary, would be a bonus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Peano arithmetic can be used to define any primitive recursive function. Checking whether a number is a base 10 palindrome can be done with a primitive recursive function. Therefore, Peano arithmetic can define a base 10 palindrome.

Comment: It is perhaps worth mentioning that the key ingredient here is Gödel's [$\beta$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gödel%27s_β_function), which allows you to quantify over finite sequences of numbers in PA.

Comment: Note that properly speaking we shouldn't talk about a *theory* defining a set/function/relation, but rather a *structure*. A theory comes into the picture once we talk about *proving facts about a given definition*. E.g. $(\mathbb{N};+,\times)$ can define the OP's set, and $\mathsf{PA}$ can prove that that set is infinite. Primitive recursion doesn't really enter into this.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Primitive recursion does enter into this. It's necessary to prove that one can come up with a first-order sentence $\phi(x)$ such that $PA \vdash \phi(S^n(0))$ iff $n$ is a base 10 palindrome. Or at least it's necessary for my proof.

Comment: @MarkSaving That's **representing**, not **defining**, a function. And primitive recursion is massive overkill: $\mathsf{PA}$ (indeed $\mathsf{Q}$ already) represents all recursive functions full stop. Primitive recursion enters into the picture once we talk about which functions a theory represents *and proves to be total*, at which point we really do hit subrecursive classes - e.g. $\mathsf{I\Sigma_1}$ gets the primitive recursive functions exactly, and $\mathsf{PA}$ gets (annoyingly enough) those functions which are "higher-type primitive recursive" in a precise sense - but that's separate.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I am aware that PA represents all recursive functions. Given that primitive recursion has a strictly simpler definition than $\mu$-recursion, I don't understand how it's overkill to discuss primitive recursive functions - if anything, it's overkill to discuss general recursion. And OP was only asking us to define a "set" - that is, to provide a predicate in PA - not to define a function. Once we have the predicate $\phi(x)$ which is derived by defining the relevant primitive recursive predicate in $PA$, we can then define the meaning of "$x$ is a palindrome" to be $\phi(x)$.